# UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight and clipping label

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I can't figure out how to do a UIButton that clips its titlelabel to the left.

When I have a UILabel and set it as NSTextAlignmentRight and NSLineBreakByClipping and get the text right-aligned and clipped on the left if it overflows.

However, on a UIBUtton, while I can set button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode to NSLineBreakByClipping, I cannot set button.titleLabel.textAlignment (doesn't do anything even in layoutSubviews). So I have to use button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight, but that does not help with clipping, the text is still clipped to the right.
i.e.

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; //Doesn't actually do anything
```

Results in right aligned, but it is clipping text to the right. I want it to clip to the left, since I am using a right-to-left script, so it does not make sense for it to clip that way.

Any way to do it without subclassing the button with a custom UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is set the button’s attributedTitle to be an attributedString with the a custom `NSParagraghStyle` that has its `lineBreakMode` set to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead`.